# USB or CD don't detects on boot menu

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb

I bought new Acer ES1-533-P21L Laptop having Linpus Linux. The issue is I can't get option for usb nor for DVD in boot menu. Help me in this situation. Thanks in advance.![image: In these I had connected usb as well as dvd][image: Nothing do display]

Answer (score 0):

First, update to the latest BIOS. At this time it is at least [v. 1.07](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/BIOS/BIOS/BIOS_Acer_1.07_A_A.zip?acerid=636159161799366257&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%20ES1-533&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6), but check for a later release.

Second, Acer restricts boot options on some models if you have not set a (UEFI) BIOS password. Be *very* careful to verify and record the password, because unlocking BIOS without it may require physical disassembly of the machine.

After that, you *might* need to disable Secure Boot and Trusted Platform Module (TPM).

That said, there is [a thread on similar issues with this model](http://community.acer.com/t5/E-F-V-and-M-Series-Laptops/Acer-Aspire-ES-15-ES1-533-C3UW-Legacy-BIOS-Missing/td-p/471754). Please let me know if setting the password helps.

Comment: Hi @DrMoishe, I got it finally in this bios settings there is only UEFI mode is available and windows 7 don't recognize on UEFI mode. So I made windows 10 bootable and it worked for me.